# Making objects aware of their (consistent) IDs

Tags: design, object-oriented, data-structures

### Abstracted problem

I would like to be able to quickly refer to some (most likely non-hashable) objects. At the same time, I would like them to be aware of their own identity. The 2-way search should be consistent, so at no point should an object give out an identity, which would return another object, had someone requested it.

### On more practical terms

I would like to be able to refer to an object quickly by some ID. In principle, this object would be non-hashable, preventing it from being used as a key in dictionary. At the same time, it should be aware of its own identity, as it would pass it to another objects: recipients of its messages so they could reach it back (for example by finding it by ID in a dictionary).

Because I cannot use the objects as key, I cannot easily create a reverse dictionary. Another intuitive solution would be to store IDs as properties in objects, but then I get no guarantee that they match the actual index of an element in said data structure. Even assuming that they would not change over time, this property would be as good as my code assigning them in the first place; a pain not known if only a dictionary had been used.

Finally, I could make the objects find their position in data structure each time they send an "envelope", but that's quite wasteful, if the data structure is not crafted to be searchable in this direction.

Have I missed a clever data organisation scheme that would lift this burden out of my mind? Do I start from completely unreasonable angle, that the objects should be findable by short (e.g. integer) id in a global data structure like dictionary?

Comment: I'm team "store IDs as properties". It seems to be the only solution that doesn't have other severe problems. You correctly note potential consistency issues, but you're usually not trying to sabotage yourself. Depending on language there might be tricks to improve safety, e.g. using a custom type for IDs that can only be constructed within the entity's owner (like a database interface), and cannot be constructed within client code /business logic. Regarding reverse lookups, note that an object's *address* can often be used as a key.

Comment: *"Another intuitive solution would be to store IDs as properties in objects, but then I get no guarantee that they match the actual index of an element in said data structure. "* - sorry, but I have trouble to understand this. Which data structure you are talking of at that point, and why should an ID (which might be a GUID, no number) "match some index" here? An object with a unique, immutable string ID as a property should do the trick, I don't understand which issues you see with that approach.

Comment: I've seen the 2 approach, the 1st is elegant but require a mutable ID in your object: the ORM works like this, the 2nd is more robust but require an envelop, it's what is used in elasticsearch. maybe theses 2 examples will help you see in which case you are.

Comment: What makes the objects unhashable, mutability?  What issues are you facing with assigning a key to each object and using that as a key in a dictionary?  Using complex objects as keys in a dictionary tends to have limited usefulness because you need to create an equivalent object in order to find the mapping.

Comment: @DocBrown The data structure I talked about was ID → object. The problem I noted with ID as property is that I get no guarantee from the language that at some point I wouldn't produce 2 objects with the same ID, the same way I'd be prevented to add second object under a key in a dictionary.

Comment: @JimmyJames Assigning a key to each object and storing them in a dictionary is not a problem. What I had conceptual troubles with is doing reverse search, having in mind the risk when ID is stored as a property (see comment above).

Comment: @amon Thank you. Like you mentioned, the availability of these solutions could differ between languages, but the first one seems very elegant, while the second might be more versatile and easier to implement. I will remember both.

Comment: *"that I get no guarantee from the language that at some point I wouldn't produce 2 objects with the same ID,"* - sorry, but what has this to do with the programming language? I think this is a property of the generation process. For example, using GUIDs as IDs will guarantee that the risk of getting an ID collision is so low you can assume no duplicate IDs for all practical purposes.

Comment: @pdem It's interesting to hear that the envelope solution is actually used in practice. Do you know if the elements find themselves each time when the envelope is created, or is this information stored elsewhere? I suppose it's not the overhead caused by the envelope's size that's problematic.

Comment: @DocBrown Fair point.

Comment: @Etua To add to what DocBrown mentioned, if you are using random (version 4) [UUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), the chance of collisions is low.  If you use a MAC-address-based UUIID (version 1 or 2) you are guaranteed to never have a collision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Is the ID (identity) of an object immutable?

If you use a randomized identifier such as a UUID you can create the ID at the same time as you create the object. If you need to persist the object into a datastore you would typically preserve the ID, in short the ID is immutable.

If you use a "natural" key/ID such as an email address there will typically be some scenario where the key needs to be updated (user changes their email address). In reality this will probably be limited to a specific transaction, so if you separate that from the rest of the logic you can probably assume that the ID is immutable (most of the time).

If you use a database to automatically assign an ID when you persist a record (auto-increment column) then your objects identity is volatile, typically the object won't have an identity until it is persisted for the first time. This can be exacerbated if an in memory object is persisted to multiple tables - for example an update to an existing object can create new child records (which initially don't have an identity).
A work around for this is to use a DB Sequence so that you can generate the ID at the same time as a new object is created - it's a little inefficient (you make a lot of round trips to the DB), but semantically it very similar to the first UUID solution.

(Array) Indexes are fine for immutable structures (or append only structures), however if the first element of an array is removed, it become necessary to update all references to subsequent elements. If removal of elements is possible, the identity of the objects in the array becomes mutable.

## How to store the ID

If you need to persist an object, most data-stores will guide you in a particular direction:

- You would typically make the ID the primary key in a SQL/Relational Database.
- A document store would similarly store the ID as part of the document.
- Key/Value stores would typically separate the ID from the "value", but you could add the ID to the value as well.

After loading an object from a datastore, if you need to persist it again you will need to retain the identity in memory. If your ID is immutable it is usually "just easier" to retain the ID as a property of the object, there may be a small amount of duplication - for example if you also need the ID as part of a Map key, but it saves having to pass the ID around all the time.

If the ID is mutable you probably need to spend more time on the design, you may choose to:

- Include the ID in the object (and update it when necessary).
- Create a wrapper containing a header (with the ID) and a body with the rest of the object.
- Maintain the ID separate in all of your code.

I don't think there is a clear winner here - it really depends upon your use case.

## Your Questions

> At no point should an object give out an identity, which would return another object, had someone requested it.

This requirement is satisfied as long as your identifiers are immutable and unique.

> Another intuitive solution would be to store IDs as properties in objects

The critical point is that the ID is logically and permanently associated with the object, not that it is stored as an attribute of the object.

> I get no guarantee that they match the actual index of an
> element in said data structure.

If you assume that the data-structure as a whole has an ID and the child object (at index X in the array) is part of the child's identity i.e.: `ID:X` then you are fine as long as elements cannot be deleted from the array (either the length/position is fixed or elements are only added at the end).

If deletes/replacements are possible then you are correct - you get no guarantees and I would say that trying to use a index to refer to a different object will likely cause problems.

> I could make the objects find their position in data structure each time they send an "envelope"

If you are "searching" regularly that would imply a different structure would be appropriate (for example a HashMap) - if you need to support multiple "searches" you could create multiple HashMaps with different keying. However it now becomes necessary to update the HashMaps when the underlying properties change.

## Addressing the Comment

I had not considered soft deletes - that is a viable strategy if records are/were deleted infrequently - the choice of implementation would probably depend upon data store used:

- If using a document store it may make sense to replace entries in the array with a `null` value to preserve the indexes, but indicate the the data no longer exists.
- For a relational DB it may make more sense to have a flag (or deletion date) on the record to indicate it had been deleted.

The email address was more of an example to indicate the issues associated with natural keys. Specifically it's really hard to find any natural key that will absolutely never change (even something like a SSN may need to be edited - if someone typo's it).

Simply put **MUTABLE** primary keys are a pain:

- If the schema has non-null foreign key constraints, it can be the case that the simplest solution is to copy the entire structure then delete the old one.
- Some databases also have weird quirks (particularly with respect to replication), if you change the primary key.

In short the comment is correct - the only way to ensure your primary keys are immutable it to make them artificial (UUID or Int).

Comment: "_fine as long as elements cannot be deleted from the array_" It's easy to support (occasional) deletes by setting a [tombstone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tombstone_(programming)) flag, so position remains fixed. Downside is you might need to copy out just the live records if too many dead ones accumulate. // The "mutable email as ID" example is an interesting one. Typical RDBMS design would be to have immutable PK (integer or UUID) with UNIQUE index, and then the `email` column _also_ has UNIQUE index. Now the API can use either, whichever better fits a given use case.

Comment: Thank you. I made a mistake by using the word "index" in my question, since I meant "any identifier the element can be referred by", so an index in an array, but also a key in a dictionary. I didn't want to make an impression, that my chosen structure is specifically an array. Of course all of your points remain valid regardless. One question I have is if you could explain the sentence: "If you assume that the data-structure as a whole has an ID (...)" Did you mean that the array stores the IDs which (logically) are part of child's (object's) identify? Why would the whole array have an ID?

Comment: It's probably best to explain by example: If I had a Sales Order (which has its own ID) and that contained multiple line items (stored in an array) it might be viable to identify each line item using a composite id composed of `SO_ID:Line_Item_Index`.